# .get() different page numbers each time?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create an infinite scroll effect (don't want to have to resort to plugins when
I don't have to). I've got the conditions set (when you hit the bottom it's set to do something) and I can make it load one page correctly, but I don't understand how to make it load different pages each time it's activated. page/2/ page/3/ page/4/ and so on.

```
 $.get('/page/2/ #posts',function(data) {
 $("#posts", data).appendTo("#pages");
```

...and a side question. Is it possible to put variables inside selectors. Say

```
 var page = something;
 $.get('page #posts', function...
```

I'm still a bit unfamiliar with jQuery syntax.

Comment: Variables inside selectors: `$.get('/page/' + your_variable + '/ #posts', function());`

Comment: Okay, I sort of figured it out. I added a count variable and then count++ every time I reached the bottom of the page. It's a bit jumpy (double posts) if I scroll down to fast, but I think I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get('/page/' + pagenum + '/#posts',function(data) {
```

And, no you can't reference variables by name within selectors, though you can concatenate them

And just to be clear, the first parameter to `$.get()` is a URL, not a selector. The code you have above does not have a valid URL, so it will fail, as no spaces are allowed in URLs (unless you're going to encode them).

Comment: There's a space before the `#`

Comment: which wouldn't be a valid URL, so I assume it's a typo

Comment: Yeah, I was retrieving a selector. Thanks. What I'm still totally confused about is how to actually generate those page number and add 1 every time I hit the bottom of the page (that last part I have down).

Comment: @StephenThomas my mistake, it's `.load()` that allows you to retrieve a selector, not `.get()` - might be useful to note this in your answer. Docs: `The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter.`

Comment: .get also allows you to retrieve a selector if you do what I did. The problem with using .load is that it replaces the content instead of appending to it.